# Storing every new PHP object in array on instantiation

Tags: php, oop, object, php4

I'm pretty new to OOP, but I have a class, and with each object created, I'm pushing them into an array (I don't think there's a way to iterate over every object in a class).  My client is still on PHP4, so I was having some trouble.

Since version 4 doesn't come with the __construct method, I made my own:

```
function construct() {
    global $LIST;
    array_push($LIST, &$this);
}
```

Without the `&` before `$this`, it's just adding an empty object into the array because after it's instantiated, I change some properties for each object.  Now it's throwing me a warning, though:

`Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated - argument passed by value; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of array_push(). If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file.`

I tried to just suppress the warning, but a @ in front of the `array_push()` doesn't work.  And apparently the `error_reporting(0)` won't work unless it's in my root file (all of this stuff is inside of an include on many, many pages).  I don't have access to the php.ini file either.

Comment: First, why?!?!  If you must, build a simple registry class maybe?  Also, in PHP4 a function with the same name as the class is automatically called as the constructor.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Why do I want all of the objects stored in an array?  Each object is a product on my client's site, and certain pages need to list all of their products.

Comment: So you built objects to represent specific products and the only time the app knows what products are available is when you manually instantiate them?  I smell a serious design flaw here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that it only works with `&$this` as the error message states that it is passing the object by value [aka, as `$this`] anyways.

Additionally, `global` in a class declaration? Bad. Horribad. Why are you not doing the following instead?

```
$LIST[] = new MyObject();
```

And if PHP4 is so archaic that the `$arr[]` syntax is not yet valid, then:

```
array_push($LIST, new MyObject());
```

Also, holy god. PHP4? Upgrade it. Seriously. I don't think you can possibly come up with a valid reason to still be using PHP4 at this point.

Comment: PHP 4 just started using Classes and Objects and you can't rely on PHP 4. Sammitch is right, you need an upgrade!

Comment: How would I get get the latest index of the $LIST once I push it on there because I need to change some properties as soon as it goes on there.

Comment: Nevermind.  I just pushed each object onto $LIST and with the object I passed an array with all my variables.  Thanks for the idea, @Sammitch.